# Как изменить css ссылки если она ведет сама на себя?

Tags: javascript, css, url, ссылки

Есть ли какое-то простое решение например в виде скрипта? Нужно изменить стиль кнопки, если ее ссылка ведет сама на себя.

Например, менять цвет кнопки активного товара на сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше добавить нужной ссылке какой-нибудь отдельный класс, а в css уже ссылаться на этот класс

Comment: Думал так, но проблема в том что CMS специфическая, верстка подтягивается динамически, если задать класс, то он будет для всех ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

```
// получаем необходимый элемент
let elem = document.querySelector(selector)
// проверяем выполняется ли необходимое нам условие
if (elem.getAttribute('href') == elem.textContent) {
    // если условие выполняется, то вешаем на этот элемент необходимый класс
    elem.classList.add('other_color')
}
```

В css добавляем необходимые стили для класса `other_color`

**Upd:** пояснение:
Этот кусок кода добавляет класс `other_color` на выбранный элемент, если атрибут href соответствует текстовому содержанию элемента

Comment: Спасибо, а как это подвязать на кнопочку? Добавить класс other_color? Если добавляю класс на бекенде, то меняется цвет всех кнопочек - https://prnt.sc/u1qh3f

Comment: @AlexRuban Добавил пояснение

Comment: Попробовал внедрить Вашу рекомендацию, но вроде не совсем сработало, класс с кнопочке не подвязывается, вот скрин как подключил - https://prnt.sc/u2257v

Comment: @AlexRuban наверное нужно писать код не в одну строчку и указать css селектор вместо `selector` в моём коде? =)

Answer (score 1):

```
function end(url){
    return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
}

[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].filter(el=>(
    end(el.href) === end(document.location.href)
)).forEach(el=>{
    el.classList.add('current')
})
```

`end` в примере сравнивает по "имени файла".
Как нужно в конкретном случае -- трудно сказать.
Разные ссылки могут вести в одно место.

---

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].filter(el => el.href === document.location.pathname).forEach(el=>{
    el.classList.add('current')
})
```

Comment: Идея выделить кнопочку цветом, если мы находимся на соответствующем товаре. Если перейти на товар "1Л" – то там скрипт по задумке сам должен изменить цвет кнопочки проверив активную ссылку на которой мы находимся. Пробовал задать классами, но бекенд генерирует динамически, по этому стили работают для всех кнопочек сразу.

Comment: тогда `.filter(el => el.href === document.location.pathname).`

Comment: можно добавить класс `.current` в какой-то css

Comment: Попробовал внедрить, но почему-то стили класса '.current' применятся ко всем ссылкам. - https://prnt.sc/u22cgx

Comment: один filter вместо другого